# Removing deck frame attached to siding

Tags: deck, removal, siding, nails, demolition

I'm in the process of removing an old deck attached to my house in an effort to replace it with stairs and a paver patio.

I've gotten most of it torn down and removed, but I'm wondering what the best way to handle removing this last bit of the frame is.

It's nailed directly into the siding, so is my best option to just rip it out and repair/replace the piece of siding afterwards?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Going by the drip edge over top the ledger it appears indeed that there is siding behind the ledger.

You can confirm this by measuring the distance from the front of the cut joist to the siding and on its other side to the ledger, and there would be 1.5in difference.

The ledger may be nailed all the way through the siding and through any sheathing into the bottom plate, which is structural. Expect long and strong 8d nails.

You should thus be able to remove the ledger and the siding will appear behind it, which you can then paint to match.

You can remove the drip edge, and lever off the ledger with a break iron etc.. An alternative is to cut the ledger's nails by carefully cutting between the ledger and the siding, reaching in from the top, with a 6in reciprocal saw.